# Lua - io.read sends me an echo back when I read from serial port - why?

Tags: lua, serial-port, openwrt

I am writing a code in Lua to read from a serial port, but when I read I receive an echo back with the code :

```
print("Dragino Uart Test started\n")
while 1 do
    serialin=io.open("/dev/ttyS0","r")
    print(serialin:read())    --print the data
    serialin:close()
end
```

When I open minicom to send him some data, I enable local echo than I type "text" and I see :

> tteexxtt

Then I need to press enter to see my message in my lua script.

I am using a OpenWRT in a Dragino.

It seems that it is like a prompt command that you type every thing that you see and you need to press enter to send you command.

There is any other way to read and write to/from a serial port?

Can somebody help me please? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The `read` method with no arguments reads a full line. That's why you need to press enter at the end of the text. Try reading one byte at a time with `:read(1)` or all of it with `:read("*a")`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. read(1) wait for the new line and just send me the first character, I didn't try read("*a") yet, I will try and I will tell you what I get.

Answer (score 0):

I don know if this is still an issue to someone but maybe this helps a few people. Like lhf said :read(1) is a gread way of doing this. I had a few problems with :read("*a") though. In my opinion the easiest way of doing this is to append the answer piece by piece like:

```
rserial=io.open("/dev/ttyS0",'r')
lines = ""
repeat
    local line=rserial:read(1)
    if string.sub(line, 0, 3) == "OED" then  --OED is here the stream ending. This can vary
            EOD = true
            rserial:close()
    elseif line then
            lines = lines .. line 
    end
until EOD == true
print (lines)
```